# codeigniter pagination showing all query results in one page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

hi every one i am trying to display mysql database records using codeigniter pagination..for that i written the following below codes..and when i run this it shows me all the results in one page while the page numbers are displayed right according to the given per_page limit..

Model:

```
  function get_records($user_name, $limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(cid) AS cIDs');
    $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
    $this->db->group_by("company_user");

    $this->db->from('company_records');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function count_records($user_name) {
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(cid) AS cIDs');
    $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
    $this->db->group_by("company_user");
    return $this->db->count_all('company_records');
   }
```

Controller:

```
    $this->load->model('Records', 'Records', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'records/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Records->count_records($this->session->userdata('user'));
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    /* $start = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; */
    if ($this->uri->segment(4) > 0) {
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(4) + 0) * $config['per_page'] - $config['per_page'];
    } else {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(4);
    }
    $data['recordsDetails'] = $this->Records->get_records($this->session->userdata('user'), $config["per_page"], $offset);
    $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

i have tried google search and stackoverflow.. but not yet found any solutions to this..may be i have issue with the query or i dont know..

please help me...

Comment: You count_records doesn't seems right

Comment: Sir can you suggest me how can i count...

Comment: i have tried `$config['total_rows'] = 15` from 
`$config['total_rows'] = $this->Records->count_records($this->session->userdata('user'));`

but this is again not working

Comment: is the uri_segment correct?

Comment: `http://localhost/company/records` this is my url..

Comment: i have tried with 3, 4 even 5

Comment: uri segment is 3. ur pagination url will be li ke `http://localhost/company/records/index/1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45923/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-muhammad)

Answer (score 1):

I used this code for pagination.

In the **model**

```
    //Search for results
    public function search($id, $table, $pageNumber) {

        //Get the number of pages
        $numOfPage = $this->findResults($id, $table, RETURN_NUM_OF_PAGES, $pageNumber);

        if ($numOfPage < 1) {
            return false; //If there are no search results return false
        } else {
            $row = array();
            $res = $this->findResults($id, $table, RETURN_RESULTS, $pageNumber);
            for ($j = 0; $j < $res->num_rows(); $j++) {
                $row[$j] = $res->row($j);
            }
            return $row; //Return the results
        }
    }

    // Find the results from DB and return number of pages/ results
    function findResults($id, $table, $returnType, $pageNumber) {

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('reputation', 'desc'); //Order the users by reputation
        $itemsPerPage = 4;

        $startingItem = ($pageNumber - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

        if ($returnType == RETURN_RESULTS) {
            $res = $this->db->get($table, $itemsPerPage, $startingItem);
            return $res; //Return the results
        } else { //Return the number of pages
            $res = $this->db->get($table);
            $count = $res->num_rows(); //Get the total number of results

            $numofPages = (int) ($count / $itemsPerPage);
            if ($count % $itemsPerPage != 0)
                $numofPages = $numofPages + 1; //If the number of items < $itemsPerPage there should be 1 page
            return $numofPages; //Return the number of pages
        }
    }
```

So from the **controller** you have to call the function *search($id, $table, $pageNumber)*.
Also the constants were defined in config/constants.php file as follows.

```
define('RETURN_NUM_OF_PAGES', 0);
define('RETURN_RESULTS', 1);
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR, i have solved this issue.... thank you again for your important time...